# VSCode not Working with WSL. What's the issue here?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've used VS Code and WSL-Ubuntu for months prior without issue. Then stopped using WSL for a while. Now I came back to it attempting to open VS Code in the WSL-Ubuntu terminal with "code ." with no response; just started a new command line but did not open the window.

When I attempted to open WSL through VS Code as a "Remote Window," I noticed that the terminal listed some response, which I cannot fully understand. It refused to open WSL with an error message box displaying: "VS Code Server for WSL: closed unexpectedly. Check WSL terminal for more details."

The terminal output:

```
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.807] Extension version: 0.81.8
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.808] L10N bundle: undefined
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.820] authorityHierarchy: wsl+Ubuntu
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.820] WSL extension activating for a local WSL instance
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.827] Resolving wsl+Ubuntu, resolveAttempt: 1
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.832] WSL feature installed: true (dll path)
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.832] NodeExecServer run: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe --list --verbose
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.982] 3 distros found
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.983] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (wsl2)
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.983] Windows build: 19045. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.983] Scriptless setup: false
[2024-01-06 00:21:22.983] No shell environment set or found for current distro.
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.151] WSL daemon log file: 
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.155] Probing if server is already installed: if [ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2 ]; then printf 'install-found '; fi; if [ -f /etc/alpine-release ]; then printf alpine-; fi; uname -m
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.155] NodeExecServer run: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e sh -c if [ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2 ]; then printf 'install-found '; fi; if [ -f /etc/alpine-release ]; then printf alpine-; fi; uname -m
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.374] Probing result: install-found x86_64
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.374] Server install found in WSL
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.375] NodeExecServer run: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2 stable code-server .vscode-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=225704189-2445177-1047782577-2906989467 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all'
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.580] Setting up server environment: Looking for /home/junix/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.580] WSL version: 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 Ubuntu
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.580] WSL-shell-PID: 1481
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.580] Node executable: /home/junix/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/node
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.580] Starting server: /home/junix/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/bin/code-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=225704189-2445177-1047782577-2906989467 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.581] For help with startup problems, go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2024-01-06 00:21:23.582] NodeExecServer run: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e kill 1481
[2024-01-06 00:21:24.663] Download in background is enabled
```

Expected to open a folder from WSL-Ubuntu in VS Code.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error in the logs. Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu? Backup your files inside WSL to your Desktop or somewhere you can find it easily, and uninstall and then install Ubuntu for WSL again.

Comment: @Andrew I really wanted to avoid doing that, but since you're not seeing any errors, I'll do it.

Comment: I'm sorry for commenting so late, but have you got it working? I fixed issues with `fish`, `zsh` in WSL before I bought a UNIX Mac, just through reinstalling so I'm pretty sure it's fixed. If not, try using Windows Terminal or `wsl.exe` to enter Ubuntu through cmd or powershell, then use `code .` and see that command works. If not, there is a high chance it's one of your extensions or VSCode is trying to open a socket port to connect to Ubuntu, but that port is already claimed or smth, the only time I saw similar logs to you was when I had trouble "installing vscode for wsl" in the first place

Comment: WSL and VS Code refused to work after uninstalling and reinstalling WSL at first. However, after typing 'wsl --install' in Powershell (admin mode), rebooting my pc, and failing to list available WSL distros via 'wsl -l', I kept getting an error similar to the following:
" ...(Exitcode: 1603).
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/E_ABORT1"
This led me to resolve the issue by following this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10764#issuecomment-1815485695
Telling me to delete Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WslService in "regedit".
Now VSCode works with WSL

Comment: Hm, maybe to do a full uninstallation and reinitialization of Ubuntu? I'll look up more about it and possibly find other people who are struggling. It's great that you got it fixed

Comment: The same issue here.

Comment: PS It works with a fresh WSL Ubuntu installation.